# How to apply the logic if the key in map is not found based on condition?

Tags: java

I have following code :

```
for(String s1 : source){
    for(String s2 : target){
        if(s1.length() > 4 && s2.length() > 4){
            String sKey = s1.substring(1,5);
            String tKey = s2.substring(1,5);
            if(sKey.equals(tKey)){
                //Do your logic...
            }else if(!sKey.equals(tKey) && sKey not availlable in the target list){
                //print the value that sKey not availlable in target
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to print the value if key is not found throughout the complete traversing of the list.

Please help !!

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: If the key is not available in second list, then i have to print that this key is not available in the target/second list and vice versa.

Comment: Is that a list or a map or do you have one of each? Your title says ‘map’, but your for loops don’t treat `source` and `target` as maps, and your text says `traversing of the list`. Is `target` is a `List<String>`?

Comment: I am getting the list from map : Map<String,List<String>> sourceTags = sourceList.get(block);

Comment: Thanks for trying to clarify. It’s still unclear to me. If you’re to save your question, I believe that a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will be needed. Including precise desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution is to add a condition, and check that condition at the end.

```
for(String s1 : source){
    boolean found = false;
    for(String s2 : target){
        if(s1.length() > 4 && s2.length() > 4){
            String sKey = s1.substring(1,5);
            String tKey = s2.substring(1,5);
            if(sKey.equals(tKey)){
                found=true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(found){
        //found logic
    } else{
        //not found logic
    }
}
```

The problem with this, you are making a new sub-string each time. Instead I would suggest creating a list of keys.

```
List<String> targetKeys = target.stream().filter(
           s->s.length()>4
     ).map(
           s->s.substring(1,5)
     ).collect(Collectors.toList());

List<String> sourceKeys = source.stream().filter(
           s->s.length()>4
     ).map(
           s->s.substring(1,5)
     ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then you can do things like.

```
sourceKeys.removeAll(targetKeys);
```

Where you would be left with only keys that don't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `contains` method from `List`

```
if (!targetList.contains(sKey)) {
// System.out.println("this will print only if the sKey not present in targetList");
}
```

Comment: If you notice the key's are not necessarily the full string in the lists.

Answer (score 0):

If I get correctly what you are trying to do, this should do it:

```
                } else if (!target.stream().map(s -> s.substring(1, 5)).anyMatch(s -> s.equals(tKey))) {
```

You don’t need the `!sKey.equals(tKey)` part of the condition since you are in the `else` part of the first `if` statement, so we already know the keys are not equal.

Since we are now doing the `substring(1, 5)` in three places in the code, you may want to factor it out into a separate method.

It’s an aside, I suggest moving this line:

```
        String sKey = s1.substring(1, 5);
```

It might as well go between the two `for (String` lines. No need to take out the substring from `s1` once for every `s2`.